# Convert string with single digit month and date string to class Date

Tags: string, r, date

I have a date in the string format of 232014 4:20 standing for 02/03/2014 04:20. I am wondering how I can transform this string to a real date format (class `Date`)?

Thank you!

Comment: If it had `1122014` would you want it to be interpreted as `01/12/2014` or `11/02/2014`?

Answer (score 4):

You will not be able to. Your format is ambiguous. For example, if you have 1122014 is that 1/12/2014 or 11/2/2014?

Comment: Apparently I was commenting at the same time you were answering, and we chose the same example bad date. Nice.

Comment: Thank you! I have a related question. THe date in excel csv format, is stored as "2/3/2014 4:20", however, after using read.csv, it is read into R as "232014 4:20". Could you tell me how to correct this?

Comment: @user2495069 It's not recognizable as a date, for the same reason as above: it's ambiguous. R did the right thing: just read in the date/time in its raw format.

Answer (score 0):

if your csv is saved as "02/03/2014 04:20"

```
x<-read.csv(..., as.is=T)
x[,1]<-strptime(as.character(x[,1]), "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M")
```